# Calling another smart contracts function which executes an event

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design

I am trying to call another contracts function. When I test this in remix and inspect the transaction I don't see that the event is executed. No error is display either.

I execute `check` function in `caller.sol` passing the `callee.sol` contract address but the event never runs

caller.sol

```
contract Caller {        
    function check(address callbackAddress) returns (string) {
           callbackAddress.call(bytes4(sha3("callMe")));
           return 'something';  
    }
}
```

callee.sol

```
contract Callee {  
    event EventTest(string value1);

    function callMe(string value) returns (string) {
            EventTest('testing')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
callbackAddress.call(bytes4(sha3("callMe")));
```

uses the wrong function signature. It should be this:

```
callbackAddress.call(bytes4(sha3("callMe(string)")));
```

Always make sure to check the return value of `call()`. I assume it's failing here, so the issue isn't that the event isn't being logged; it's that the call fails (because there's no matching function selector).

**EDIT**

Working code I tested after silencing all the compiler warnings and adding a `require` to make sure the call was succeeding:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Caller {
    function check(address callbackAddress) public {
        require(callbackAddress.call(bytes4(keccak256("callMe(string)"))));
    }
}

contract Callee {  
    event EventTest(string value1);

    function callMe(string) public {
        EventTest('testing');
    }
}
```

I tested in Remix with the JavaScript VM by first deploying `Callee` and then deploying `Caller` and invoking `check` with the address of the deployed `Callee`. The event was logged as expected.

Changes I made are below. Only the first two are necessary to make the code work:

- Use `"callMe(string)"` to get the correct function selector.
- Add a semicolon at the end of `EventTest('testing')`.
- Specify a compiler version.
- Get rid of the return type on `check`, since it's going to be invoked by a transaction.
- Explicitly mark `check` as `public`.
- Use `keccak256` instead of (the deprecated) `sha3`.
- Drop the return type from `callMe`, since it's going to be invoked via `call` and wasn't returning anything anyway.
- Drop the name of `callMe`'s parameter, since it's unused.
- Explicitly mark `callMe` as `public`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but still no luck

Comment: I edited my post to include the working code.

Comment: Thanks. I am using my local testrpc and expecting to see the event in the `decoded output` section in remix. Should it be displayed there in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Sorry, no, it should be in the "logs" section in Remix. I just tested with `ganache-cli`, and it works there too.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, perhaps you can share the exact code you're using? (The code you shared didn't compile due to a missing semicolon, so it can't have been the exact code you were using.)

Comment: I have what you have. Let me look into it a little further. I expect to see the event logged but don't - https://imgur.com/a/gD6Vh

Comment: If I use a string address as the parameter then I get - https://imgur.com/a/13MSR

Comment: That looks right to me. Addresses need to be quoted strings in Remix. I think something recently changed, because I no longer see an error message when I fail to use quotes.